# File Browser no grapelli: NameError: name 'site' is not defined

Tags: django, python-3.6, django-tinymce, django-filebrowser, django-2.1

I'm following [this tutorial](https://fosstack.com/how-to-set-up-tinymce-in-django-app/) for install *django-tinymce4-lite*. At the end of the tutorial there are the indications to install *django-filebrowser-no-grappelli*.

I use Django 2.1.1 but even though I've followed all the indications, after the installation of the file browser was shown this message:

> File
>   "/var/www/html/dev/miosito/django/beautifulsite_v0.1.1/djangosite/djangosite/urls.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       path('admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),  NameError: name 'site' is not defined

Here there is urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from filebrowser.sites import site #sorry I've forgot this

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('testapp.urls')), #app for my tests
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    path('admin/filebrowser/', include('site.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What I've wrong?

***EDIT after Yeo correction:***

I've add the string that I've forgot and I've correct

```
path('admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),
```

with

```
path('admin/filebrowser/', include('site.urls')),
```

but now I've this new error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'site.urls'; 'site' is not a
>   package

Comment: you forget the `from filebrowser.sites import site`

Comment: Now I've another error

Comment: Why you're not following the tutorial? use this instead
`path('admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)), `

Comment: if you quote the `site.urls`, then it means different things...

Comment: Yeo I've already use the quote on site.urls and I've this error:

Comment: File "/var/www/html/dev/miosito/django/beautifulsite_v0.1.1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 27, in include
    'provide the namespace argument to include() instead.' % len(arg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to inc
lude() instead.

Comment: Then I've tried in another way as you see...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180623/discussion-between-yeo-and-massimiliano-moraca).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following: (remove the `include`)

```
# ...
from filebrowser.sites import site
# ...

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('admin/filebrowser/', site.urls),
    # ...
]
```

Always refer to the package official documentation, when you encounter errors specific to the package itself. (In this case is [django-filebrowser](https://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation), although the main repo seems to be at [django-filebrowser-no-grappelli](https://github.com/smacker/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli)). Blog sometime gets outdated easily. For example the guide from your link does not specify what Django version they are using. (Looking from the way the tutorial was written `include`, it seems to be Django<1.9 [(reference)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#passing-a-3-tuple-or-an-app-name-to-include)).

If you're using Django>=2, then the official document should explain the correct way to install this package.